# Ionic runtime error while running on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to run app using ionic and cordova build . I am getting error while running following command on command line. I also tried updating ionic and angular to latest build still showing me same error
ionic cordova run android. Can you please help solving this issue. Following is my package.json file. Please have a look.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.1.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.5.3",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.0",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.6.2-alpha",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "upstox": "^1.2.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

*emphasized text*

```js
   Cannot find module 'path'.

       L8:      host: CompilerHost;
       L9:      oldProgram?: Program;
      L10:  }): Program?
 Error: Failed to transpile program
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dis
t\util\errors.js:16:2   Cannot find module 'path'.

       L8:      host: CompilerHost;
       L9:      oldProgram?: Program;
      L10:  }): Program?
 Error: Failed to transpile program
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dis
t\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:1
59:20
    at transpileWorker (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\di
st\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\d
ist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:8
2`8)
    at F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:1
59:20
    at transpileWorker (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\di
st\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\d
ist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at F:\Ionic apps\cricket\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:8
2`
```

Comment: Have you tried `npm install path --save`?